# Adding a dash in a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(day1,1)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Sum(day1 + day2)) AS day2
    FROM   DaysTable
    WHERE day1 is Not null AND  day2 is Not null
```

I'm trying to return values from two columns in the same table and also add the two columns which and also add the two columns which will return as one acolumn. Also i want to add a dash line between the results.So my results will look like this 20-30

Comment: Looks like you're missing some casts.  Try casting your substrings: SUBSTRING(CAST(day1 as nvarchar(2)),1)  etc...

Comment: You expect to take a substring of something that is not a string?

Comment: If 2012+, you can use concat() instead of cast()

Comment: What are you trying to do with `SUBSTRING()`? `SUBSTRING()` requires 3 arguments, you've given it 2 in the first usage and 1 in the second. I'm guessing you shouldn't be using it at all. What datatype are the `day1` and `day2` columns?

Comment: I'm expecting my result to be like this 20-30. So i'm basically trying to add the dash line in the middle.

Comment: And you still have not sated the datatype of day1 and day2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fields are integers:

```
SELECT CAST(day1 AS VARCHAR(25))+'-'+CAST(day1+day2 AS VARCHAR(25))
FROM   DaysTable
WHERE day1 is Not null AND  day2 is Not null
```

If they are strings you could omit the first `CAST()` and would have to add a `CAST()` around `day1` to prompt integer addition:

```
SELECT day1+'-'+CAST(CAST(day1 AS INT)+day2 AS VARCHAR(25))
FROM   DaysTable
WHERE day1 is Not null AND  day2 is Not null
```

Numbers shouldn't be stored as strings except in instances where no calculations would be done on them and/or you want to preserve leading zeroes, like SSN/phone numbers/CPT codes.

Fyi:  `SUBSTRING()` returns a portion of a string (a 'sub'set if you will):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('dog',1,2) 
-- Returns 'do', from the first character, take 2 characters.
```

`SUM()` is not needed for adding values on the same row, but is instead used when you want to aggregate values from multiple rows.  For adding or concatenating, all you need is `+` and whether it concatenates or adds is determined by the data types presented.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(day1 AS NVARCHAR(50)),1,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(CAST(Sum(day1 + day2)AS NVARCHAR(50)),1,2) AS day2
```

Comment: The `substring()`s aren't necessary. I don't think we can assume the values are two digits anyway.

Comment: This is sample only, We can adjust length of Substring or do not use Substring function as on your concept.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this all the time when I try to concatenate strings and integers, kind of same problem.

SUBSTRING is expecting a string of some sort, and isn't happy that you're giving it an integer.

So, convert your integers to strings before you do string operations on them.

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(day1 as varchar(2)),1) + '-'
```